# Running Anti-Anti-Advert Scripts?

Tags: advertising

Most websites contain adverts, and a lot of users are using software to stop adverts from loading. An example of the software used would be [AdBlock](https://adblockplus.org/).

Is it considered acceptable to either block the use of ad-blockers? For example blocking access to content until the site is white-listed? [Here](http://www.hotscripts.com/listing/saurdo-adblock-counter/) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Completely up to the webmaster but what usually happens (at least in testing I've seen on this subject) is viewers just go else ware.

Unless you are in a very specific niche or offering some sort of service that can not be obtained else ware users will most likely just go somewhere else.

A lot of the time if someone wants to disable your anti adblocker then can just edit the local version of the page (firebug / built in dev tool) to disable the js that is most likely being used to detect and lock content if an adblocker is found.

Comment: I agree that users will just fly away when they see the message, I am totally one of this users ^^

Comment: I came across a site with a message telling me to turn off Adblock and I, too, went elsewhere. My thinking is that if i don't want to see ads, it is unlikely that i would click them.